# C# Logic failure in dynamic Controls Code

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic, controls, panel

I am pretty new to programming, so please do not hate me for dirty code. I would love to get beginner friendly tips if you have some for me. And sorry for my english I hope you can understand me and maybe try my code yourself to see my problem in action.

I have a Windows form with a group box, in the group box is a panel. Directly in the Form there is a Button to add a row with a set of Controls (in my case 1 row has 2 buttons. One without sense now and one to delete the row) into the panel.

The buttons in one row should have the same tags (1-X)

So adding a row with my 2 button-set works "fine". My next plan was to delete the row when i press the delete button from a row.

After Deletion of a row which i identify with Control Tags, I want to decrease the Number Values for Name (Function 2 to Function 1 if I delete the row 1 for example), Tag and Text from each button which has a higher Tag Value than the row number which got deleted. So theres the failure somewhere I guess.

It's working fine to Add and Remove. But not if i want to add a row again. I must click multiple times then to add a new row.

To explain what I want to do:

```
|ADD ROW BUTTON| //Clicked 4 Times already

PANEL
{
|Function 1| --- |Delete 1|
|Function 2| --- |Delete 2|
|Function 3| --- |Delete 3|
|Function 4| --- |Delete 4|
}



// Clicking |Delte 2|
// Removed Row 2 and rename those which have bigger Row number as the deleted row with decreased value for the Text, Tag & Name
// So row 2 gets removed, Function 3 becomes Function 2 and Function 4 becomes Function 3

PANEL
{
|Function 1| --- |Delete 1|
|Function 2| --- |Delete 2| 
|Function 3| --- |Delete 3|
}
```

But they mostly "never" rename like i've planned in my code/mind. Only sometimes when "playing" with it it will rename a button

My Code looks like this (start with a Winform with a panel named pnl and the Row AddButton):

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int rowCount = 0;
    int lastY;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddRow();
    }

    public void AddRow()
    {
        rowCount++;
        label1.Text = rowCount.ToString();
        #region Create the Function Button in a row
        Button btnFunction = new Button();
        if (rowCount == 1)
        {
            btnFunction.Location = new Point(10, 5);
        }
        else if (rowCount > 1)
        {
            Control[] letztesY = pnl.Controls.Find($"btnFunction{rowCount - 1}", true);

            foreach (var button in letztesY)
            {
                lastY = button.Location.Y;

            }
            btnFunction.Location = new Point(10, lastY + 25);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unerwarteter Fehler");
        }

        btnFunction.Name = "btnFunction" + rowCount;
        btnFunction.Tag = rowCount;
        btnFunction.Text = "Function " + rowCount.ToString();
        pnl.Controls.Add(btnFunction);
        #endregion

        #region Create the Delete Row Button in a row
        Button btnDelete = new Button();
        if (rowCount == 1)
        {
            btnDelete.Location = new Point(85, 5);
        }
        else if (rowCount > 1)
        {
            Control[] letztesY = pnl.Controls.Find($"btnDelete{rowCount - 1}", true);

            foreach (var button in letztesY)
            {
                lastY = button.Location.Y;

            }
            btnDelete.Location = new Point(85, lastY + 25);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Fail");
        }

        btnDelete.Name = "btnDelete" + rowCount;
        btnDelete.Tag = rowCount;
        btnDelete.Text = "Delete " + rowCount.ToString();
        btnDelete.Click += new EventHandler(deleteCallerRow);
        pnl.Controls.Add(btnDelete);
        #endregion

    }

    private void deleteCallerRow(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rowCount--;
        label1.Text = rowCount.ToString();

        Button delCaller = sender as Button;

        #region DeltePressedRowDelButton
        Control[] toBeRemovedDelButtons = pnl.Controls.Find($"btnDelete{delCaller.Tag}", true);                   
        foreach (var delBtn in toBeRemovedDelButtons)
        {
            pnl.Controls.Remove(delBtn);
            delBtn.Dispose();

        }

        Control[] toBeRemovedFunctionButtons = pnl.Controls.Find($"btnFunction{delCaller.Tag}", true);
        foreach (var funcBtn in toBeRemovedFunctionButtons)
        {
            pnl.Controls.Remove(funcBtn);
            funcBtn.Dispose();

        }
        #endregion

        #region Decrease Numbers in Buttons Texts, Tags and Names
        Control[] toBeRenamedDeleteButtons = pnl.Controls.Find($"btnDelete", true);
        foreach (var db in toBeRenamedDeleteButtons)
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt32(db.Tag) > Convert.ToInt32(delCaller.Tag) )
            {
                db.Name = "btnDelete" + Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(db.Tag) - 1);
                db.Tag = Convert.ToInt32(db.Tag) - 1;
                db.Text = "Delete " + Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(db.Tag) - 1);
            }
        }

        Control[] toBeRenamedFunctionButtons = pnl.Controls.Find($"btnFunction", true);
        foreach (var fb in toBeRenamedFunctionButtons)
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt32(fb.Tag) > Convert.ToInt32(delCaller.Tag))
            {
                fb.Name = "btnFunction" + Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(fb.Tag) - 1);
                fb.Tag = Convert.ToInt32(fb.Tag) - 1;
                fb.Text = "Function " + Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(fb.Tag) - 1);
            }

        }
        #endregion


    }
}
```

So I didn't handle free spaces between rows when removing one now since I am stucking at the Problem with the Renaming doesn't work as expected.

Thanks for any help in advice.

Hope you can understand my problem.

Comment: Well if i alwas remove the last row, also multiple times, the rowCount works also when adding and loop this procedere. But if i delete some rows between and addin some new ones, the rowCounter is not true anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things going on in your code that are causing issues during your button deletion.

The first is in this block:

```
    Button delCaller = sender as Button;

    #region DeltePressedRowDelButton
    Control[] toBeRemovedDelButtons = pnl.Controls.Find($"btnDelete{delCaller.Tag}", true);                   
    foreach (var delBtn in toBeRemovedDelButtons)
    {
        pnl.Controls.Remove(delBtn);
        delBtn.Dispose();

    }

    Control[] toBeRemovedFunctionButtons = pnl.Controls.Find($"btnFunction{delCaller.Tag}", true);
    foreach (var funcBtn in toBeRemovedFunctionButtons)
    {
        pnl.Controls.Remove(funcBtn);
        funcBtn.Dispose();

    }
```

You store the sender (the button) in delCaller but then dispose of it when you find it in the panel. You then go on to use the stored button even though you've already disposed of it. You need to store the tag in another variable before you dispose of it.

The second is in this block:

```
db.Name = "btnDelete" + Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(db.Tag) - 1);
db.Tag = Convert.ToInt32(db.Tag) - 1;
db.Text = "Delete " + Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(db.Tag) - 1);
```

You change db.Tag before setting the Text, so the text will show one lower value than you're looking for.

Tested modified delete function:

```
    private void deleteCallerRow(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rowCount--;
        label1.Text = rowCount.ToString();

        Button delCaller = sender as Button;
        int callerTagNo = (int)delCaller.Tag;

        #region DeltePressedRowDelButton
        Control[] toBeRemovedDelButtons = pnl.Controls.Find("btnDelete" + callerTagNo, true);
        foreach (var delBtn in toBeRemovedDelButtons)
        {
            pnl.Controls.Remove(delBtn);
            delBtn.Dispose();

        }

        Control[] toBeRemovedFunctionButtons = pnl.Controls.Find("btnFunction" + callerTagNo, true);
        foreach (var funcBtn in toBeRemovedFunctionButtons)
        {
            pnl.Controls.Remove(funcBtn);
            funcBtn.Dispose();

        }
        #endregion

        #region Decrease Numbers in Buttons Texts, Tags and Names
        foreach (Control b in pnl.Controls)
        {
            if(b.Name.Contains("btnDelete"))
            {
                if(callerTagNo < (int)b.Tag)
                {
                    //Rename
                    int newTag = (int)b.Tag - 1;
                    b.Name = "btnDelete" + newTag;
                    b.Tag = newTag;
                    b.Text = "Delete " + newTag;
                }
            }
            else if(b.Name.Contains("btnFunction"))
            {
                if(callerTagNo < (int)b.Tag)
                {
                    //Rename
                    int newTag = (int)b.Tag - 1;
                    b.Name = "btnFunction" + newTag;
                    b.Tag = newTag;
                    b.Text = "Function " + newTag;
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

**Note**:
I would recommend using the Dock property of the controls for placement of your buttons. That would greatly simplify your adding/removing of them. I would do one of the following:

1) When adding your pair of buttons, instead of adding them to the main panel (pnl), instead add them to a new Panel and then add that panel to your main panel with the Dock property set to top. This will allow them to automatically shift when being added or removed. There are many resources on docking and WinForms to get you started on this, for example [here](http://www.functionx.com/csharp1/winprog/Lesson03.htm).

2) Use a TableLayoutPanel with 2 columns and Dock set to Fill, which will automatically shift things as well and is slightly less complex.

Best of luck.

Comment: you helped me alot. Thanks for taking the time for it. You exactly gave the help i was hoping for. Give this guy a cookie :)